# Node ReferenceError: response is not defined for an api call

Tags: node.js

I just started learning node and I am having trouble printing out the data I get on my browser. Anytime I go to the url I get this error ReferenceError: response is not defined. My thing is if you look at the code below it looks like I alreadyd defined my response. Please tell me what I am doing wrong so I can learn!

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const url = "https://remotive.io/api/remote-jobs";
const request = require("request");

app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  res.send("lets goooo");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}/jobs`);
});

app.get("/jobs", function (req, res) {
  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(body);
    }
  });
  res.send(response.body);
});
```

Comment: `res.send(response.body)` is outside the scope of the callback of `request`, but `response` is only valid inside the body of this callback

Comment: Okay that worked. DO you know why when I print it in the browser the data that I get bad looks wrong compared to how its suppposed to look? It prints out just fine on the console.log but prints out wrong in the browser.

Comment: can you send what it prints out?

Comment: How would we know? We neither know how your data is *supposed to look* nor what you mean by *bad looks wrong*

Comment: Maybe its because your res.send is response.body while the console log is just body? like how derpirscher said, how would we know?

Answer (score 0):

Edited your code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const url = "https://remotive.io/api/remote-jobs";
const request = require("request");

app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  res.send("lets goooo");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}/jobs`);
});

app.get("/jobs", function (req, res) {
  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(body);
    }
res.send(response.body);
  });
  
});
```

Always refer docs to learn any technology, Node and express framework docs [express docs](https://expressjs.com/), [node docs](https://nodejs.org/en/), [tutorials on node.js for beginners](https://www.javatpoint.com/nodejs-tutorial)

Comment: You should explain how (and why) you have changed the original code.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I will do that.

Answer (score -1):

Note: since node.js lifecycle is auto asynchronous.
What this means is when you are calling a synchronous function res.send(), this function will be called before the request function.

**From line 14**

```
app.get("/jobs", function (req, res) {
  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      res.send(response.body);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify what you are trying to implement. If you are posing the question to find out what's wrong with your code. Also lines 2 and 3 of your code snippet seem suspicious, since Express does not have a request() callback, and since the response status code is usually set by a callback, rather than being read inside of one. Please be sure to review the Express documentation

Comment: I am refering to snippet of the question and I even mentioned from line 14 replace it with the following code.